# How to copy a link to clipboard fetched from an api in react

Tags: reactjs, copy, clipboard

I tried finding information on this and there is a lot of it but nothing dealing with this particular issue.

I have a API which gives a array of JSON which also provides a link in the json itself, so in UI i have created different cards for different results a share button is placed on the cards,when onclick of share
button it should copy the links defined in JSON to clipboard.

how can i do it?
can someone please help me out in this

```
handleSubmit = (e, url) => {
const assignURL = window.copy(url);
copy(assignURL)
}

<Button
onClick={(e) =>
this.handleSubmit(e, json.link)}
>share</Button>
```

How to copy the link in handle submit which is fetched from json?

Comment: try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-clipboard.js?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.execCommand` to handle your issue:

```js
handleSubmit = (e, url) => {
  const assignURL = url
  
  assignURL.select()

  document.execCommand('copy')

  // now it is in your clipboard

}
```